# Can we always find an orthonormal base with rational vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal

Given a basis $(v_1,\ldots,v_m)$ for some vector space $V\subseteq\mathbb Q^n$ with $m\le n$, can we always find an orthonormal base for $V$ with rational basis vectors? If yes, how can we construct such a basis?

Comment: what does $(v_1,v_2\dots,v_n)$ have to do?

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo It's the basis of the vector space $V$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No we can't. Let $V\subset \mathbb Q^2$ be the line $x=y$. Every vector $(x,x)$ in $V$ has irrational length $\sqrt2 |x|$, so $V$ contains no unit vectors.

Comment: Very intuitive counterexample! Thank you.